# Why won't this Javascript scroll function work?

Tags: javascript

I am mightily confused to why this won't run. I am trying to get the click to scroll button to scroll down.

https://jsfiddle.net/n9jqvas9/

```
<script>
 $("button").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("s2text").offset().top},
    'slow');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You are missing jQuery in your example. and there is not element `s2text` It is `.s2text`

Comment: There's no such element as `s2text` in `$("s2text")`. Perhaps you meant `$(".s2text")`?

Comment: missing your class identifier .

Answer (score 3):

You are missing both jQuery (in your example) and a dot before `s2text` because it is a class.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".s2text").offset().top},
        'slow');
  });
```

Here is your updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9jqvas9/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add JQuery library and set the class selector:

```
$(".s2text").offset().top
```

Intead:

```
$("s2text").offset().top
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/lbclucascosta/n9jqvas9/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the dot (.) class name.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".s2text").offset().top},
        'slow');
  });
```